# Application setting on slot in Azure

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, azure-devops, single-page-application, release

When I run my SPA application with .net core 2.1 through pipeline in VSTS, application setting "WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE" is set on slot, but not on web app.

[image]

This prevents us from publishing from visual studio, but if we delete the setting we can deploy. 
Is there a setting in CI/CD in vsts that can prevent this setting to be set on slots when application is deployed through pipeline?

Thanks!

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, this is a setting for Azure Functions.  Can you elaborate on *how* this setting prevents you from deploying from Visual Studio?  And why would you want to deploy directly from VS if you have a CI/CD pipeline do take care of deployments for you?

Comment: This settings basically means that the filesystem on the slot is read-only, therefore I can't publish through visual studio or make an FTP connection and replace the files.
The only way then is to push the new code through pipeline, which is time consuming. 
I want the option to push code through pipeline but also be able to replace the files on the web server.

This setting is ONLY set on the slots and not on the web-app, but they have the same setting in CI/CD in Azure.

Comment: Is there a setting or a command I can put i VSTS pipeline to delete this setting after release?

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by switching the release method from "Run From Package" to "Web Deploy".

Under your Deploy Azure App Service stage, there is a heading "Additional Deployment Options", under this header:

Check Select deployment method

Select "Web Deploy" for Deployment Method

This will no longer add the flag to your configuration.